# Trying to use a variable for the criteria in autofilter with "not equal" <> and can not get it to work

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm using Excel VBA to filter a list using the "not equals" expression. If I use `Criteria1:="<>Bob"`, the code runs perfectly, but if I change "Bob" to a variable, the code does not run.

This works:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Rpt_AM_04_Sales_ShipTo").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
    Criteria1:="<>Bob", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This does not work:

```
Dim Test_Criteria As String
Test_Criteria = "Bob"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Rpt_AM_04_Sales_ShipTo").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
    Criteria1:<>Test_Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I expect the code to return a list that has everyone in it except Bob.
Instead, I get an error message just typing in the code:

```
Compile error
Expected: named parameter
```

Comment: `"<>" & Test_Criteria`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Incorrect syntax

The code does not work because of `incorrect syntax` where you specify the criteria. Try this:

Change this:

```
Criteria1:<>Test_Criteria
```

To this:

```
Criteria1:"<>" & Test_Criteria
```

Complete code:

```
Dim Test_Criteria As String
Test_Criteria = "Bob"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Rpt_AM_04_Sales_ShipTo").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
     Criteria1:="<>" & Test_Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I used your changes:
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Rpt_AM_04_Sales_ShipTo").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:"<>" & Test_Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues

But I now get a compile error: Syntax error



Any other suggestions?

Comment: @walterpayton34 After testing the code, it seems there was some special character that was causing the error. Try to re-copy this code and see if it fixes the error.

Comment: Per your recommendation, I changed this: Criteria1:"<>" & Test_Criteria to this: Criteria1:="<>" & Test_Criteria.  This fixed the problem and works perfectly.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something similar where I have an array list full of items and I want to filter them out. But when I try the 'Criteriaxl:="<>" & arrList' I am getting a type mismatch error, code below:

```
Dim idRange As Range
  Set idRange = trinWks.Range("A1:A" & lastRow(trinWks, 1))
  Dim arrList() As String, lngCnt As Long
  
  lngCnt = 0

  For Each idCell In idRange
    If Trim(idCell.Value) = vbNullString Then GoTo SkipEntry:
    ReDim Preserve arrList(lngCnt)
    arrList(lngCnt) = idCell.Value
    lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
SkipEntry:
  Next idCell
  
  On Error Resume Next
  finalTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & arrList, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34204147)